# Sequlize Fetch rows with no associated children

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

I would like to fetch all rows with no associated children.
I have this association:

```
A.hasMany(B, {
  as: 'bRecords',
  foreignKey: 'aId',
   constraints: false,
 });
B.belongsTo(A, {
 foreignKey: 'aId',
 as: 'a',
 constraints: false,
});
```

I want to fetch all the A's with no B's.
I tried this:

```
A.findAll({
  where: {
    $bRecords$: null
  },
  include: [
   model: B,
   as: 'bRecords' 
 ]
}
```

I get an error saying:

> Unknown column bRecords in where clause.

Comment: have you tried $bRecords.column$ ?

Comment: $bRecords.colmun$ "works" but not as expected. bRecords is an array not a nested object, so i think this is the real issue. How can i query where bRecords is null or an empty array.

Comment: bRecords.id = null ?

There is nothing to do with objects or javascript. You have to investigate the SQL generated.

Comment: I can do it easly with an SQL query, but i want to implement it in the way mentioned in the question